# Qt QTcpSocket Reading Data Overlap Causes Invalid TCP Behavior During High Bandwidth Reading and Writing

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, qtcpsocket

**Summary:** Some of the memory within the TCP socket to be overwritten by other incoming data.

**Application:**
A client/server system that utilizes **TCP within Qt (QTcpSocket and QTcpServer)**. The client request a frame from the server(just a simple string message), and the response (Server -> Client) which consists of that frame (614400 bytes for testing purposes). Frame sizes are established in advance and are fixed.

**Implementation Details:**
From the guarantees of the TCP protocol (Server -> Client), I know that I should be able to read the 614400 bytes from the socket and that they are in order. If any either of these two things fails, the connection must have failed.

**Important Code:**
Assuming the socket is connected.

This code requests a frame from the server. Known as the `GetFrame()` function.

```
// Prompt the server to send a frame over
if(socket->isWritable() && !is_receiving) { // Validate that socket is ready
    is_receiving = true; // Forces only one request to go out at a time
    qDebug() << "Getting frame from socket..." << image_no;
    int written = SafeWrite((char*)"ReadyFrame"); // Writes then flushes the write buffer
    if (written == -1) {
        qDebug() << "Failed to write...";
        return temp_frame.data();
    }
    this->SocketRead();
    is_receiving = false;
}
qDebug() << image_no << "- Image Received";
image_no ++;
return temp_frame.data();
```

This code waits for the frame just requested to be read. This is the `SocketRead()` function

```
size_t byte_pos = 0;
qint64 bytes_read = 0;
do {
    if (!socket->waitForReadyRead(500)) { // If it timed out return existing frame
        if (!(socket->bytesAvailable() > 0)) {
            qDebug() << "Timed Out" << byte_pos;
            break;
        }
    }
    bytes_read = socket->read((char*)temp_frame.data() + byte_pos, frame_byte_size - byte_pos);
    if (bytes_read < 0) {
        qDebug() << "Reading Failed" << bytes_read << errno;
        break;
    }
    byte_pos += bytes_read;

} while (byte_pos < frame_byte_size && is_connected); // While we still have more pixels
qDebug() << "Finished Receiving Frame: " << byte_pos;
```

As shown in the code above, I read until the frame is fully received (where the number of bytes read is equal to the number of bytes in the frame).

The issue that I'm having is that the QTcpSocket read operation is **skipping bytes** in ways that are not in line with the guarantees of the TCP protocol. Since I skip bytes I end up not reaching the end of the while loop and just "Time Out". **Why is this happening?**

**What I have done so far:**
The data that the server sends is directly converted into uint16_t (short) integers which are used in other parts of the client. I have changed the server to simply output data that just counts up adding one for each number sent. Since the data type is uint16_t and the number of bytes exceeds that maximum number for that integer type, the int-16's will loop every 65535.

This is a data visualization software so this debugging configuration (on the client side) leads to something like this:
[image: Debugging visual output]

I have determined (and as you can see a little at the bottom of the graphic) that some bytes are being skipped. In the memory of `temp_frame` it is possible to see the exact point at which the memory skipped:

[image: Memory trace for skipping]

**Under correct circumstances, this should count up sequentially.**

From Wireshark and following this specific TCP connection I have determined that **all of the bytes are in fact arriving** (all 6114400), and that **all the numbers are in order** (I used a python script to ensure counting was sequential).

This is work on an open source project so [this](https://github.com/scott-huson/LiveViewOpenSource) is the whole code base for the client.

Overall, I don't see how I could be doing something wrong in this solution, all I am doing is reading from the socket in the standard way.

Comment: Please read the description of the tags that you apply, Qt is C++ and not C. Also, don't use pictures to represent text and consider extracting a [mcve].

Comment: Although the kernel and NIC may be able to handle a high data rate, you may run out of _kernel_ socket buffers to store the data. Consider using `getsockopt` and `setsockopt` with `SO_RCVBUF` to set a larger amount of space. See `man 7 socket` for details

Comment: Ok, thanks for the suggestion @CraigEstey, I tried that but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Specifically, I used `setsockopt` and `SO_RCVBUF` to set the buffer size to 614400.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you saying you see the `"Timed Out"` debug message?  Also the comment `// If it timed out return existing frame` in `SocketRead` is a bit odd.  That in itself suggests you might end up proccessing partial frame data simply because you decided not to wait any longer.  Rather then using `waitForReadyRead` you should connect to the [`readyRead`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#readyRead) signal and process/dispatch data as/when it arrives.

Comment: I see the "Timed Out" debug message, not because I am not waiting long enough, but because there is no more data to receive in this frame. I've made sure of this through Wireshark. The reason I see no more data is because I've skipped it somehow and am prematurely reaching the end. Additionally, in the past I have tried using the ReadyRead signal but I found this method to be more reliable. @G.M.

Answer (score 0):

*Caveat:* This isn't a definitive answer to your problem, but some things to try (it's too large for a comment).

---

With (e.g.) GigE, your data rate is ~100MB/s. With a [total] amount of *kernel* buffer space of 614400, this will be refilled ~175 times per second. IMO, this is still too small. When I've used `SO_RCVBUF` [for a commercial product], I've used a minimum of 8MB. This allows a wide(er) margin for task switch delays.

Try setting something *huge* like 100MB to eliminate this as a factor [during testing/bringup].

---

First, it's important to verify that the kernel and NIC driver can handle the throughput/latency.

You may be getting too many interrupts/second and the ISR prolog/epilog overhead may be too high. The NIC card driver can implement polled vs interrupt driver with `NAPI` for ethernet cards.

See: https://serverfault.com/questions/241421/napi-vs-adaptive-interrupts

See: https://01.org/linux-interrupt-moderation

---

You process/thread may not have high enough priority to be scheduled quickly.

You can use the R/T scheduler with `sched_setscheduler`, `SCHED_RR`, and a priority of (e.g.) 8. Note: going higher than 11 kills the system because at 12 and above you're at a higher priority than most internal kernel threads--not a good thing.

---

You may need to disable IRQ balancing and set the IRQ affinity to a single CPU core.

You can then set your input process/thread locked to that core [with `sched_setaffinity` and/or `pthread_setaffinity`].

---

You might need some sort of "zero copy" to bypass the kernel copying from its buffers into your userspace buffers.

You can `mmap` the kernel socket buffers with `PACKET_MMAP`. See: https://sites.google.com/site/packetmmap/

---

I'd be careful about the overhead of your `qDebug` output. It looks like an iostream type implementation. The overhead may be significant. It could be slowing things down significantly.

That is, you're *not* measuring the performance of your system. You're measuring the performance of your system *plus* the debugging code.

When I've had to debug/trace such things, I've used a [custom] "event" log implemented with an in-memory ring queue with a fixed number of elements.

Debug calls such as:

```
eventadd(EVENT_TYPE_RECEIVE_START,some_event_specific_data);
```

Here `eventadd` populates a fixed size "event" `struct` with the event type, event data, and a hires timestamp (e.g. `struct timespec` from `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,...)`.

The overhead of each such call is quite low. The events are just stored in the event ring. Only the last N are remembered.

At some point, your program triggers a dump of this queue to a file and terminates.

This mechanism is similar to [and modeled on] a H/W logic analyzer. It is also similar to `dtrace`

Here's a sample event element:

```
struct event {
    long long evt_tstamp;               // timestamp
    int evt_type;                       // event type
    int evt_data;                       // type specific data
};
```