# Why doesn't my epoll based program improve performance by increasing the number of connections?

Tags: c, performance, optimization, epoll

I have a program which reads a file of domain names (one domain per line) and performs asynchronous DNS resolution and then downloads the landing page for each domain. The network communication is performed with an `epoll` based event loop. Testing has shown that increasing the number of concurrent connections does not increase performance in terms of Mbits/s throughput and in terms of number of pages downloaded. The results of my test are as follows. The first test is for 1024 concurrent connections, the second test for 2048, the third for 4096 and the fourth for 8192:

```
:~$ ./crawler com.lowercase 
iterations=156965 total domains=5575 elapsed=65.51s domains/s=85.10 KB=28163 Mbit/s=2.86
:~$ ./crawler com.lowercase 
iterations=88339 total domains=10525 elapsed=64.98s domains/s=161.98 KB=52936 Mbit/s=5.41
:~$ ./crawler com.lowercase 
iterations=143989 total domains=9409 elapsed=64.80s domains/s=145.20 KB=48166 Mbit/s=4.94
:~$ ./crawler com.lowercase 
iterations=109597 total domains=10532 elapsed=65.13s domains/s=161.71 KB=51874 Mbit/s=5.29
```

As you can see there is really no trend of increase in terms of domains downloaded per second or Mbits/s throughput. These results run contrary to expectations. Can anyone explain these results? Suggest a fix to improve performance with increasing number of connections?

For those interested a full code listing is provided below:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <resolv.h>
#include <sys/epoll.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ares.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define MAXWAITING 1000 /* Max. number of parallel DNS queries */
#define MAXTRIES      3 /* Max. number of tries per domain */
#define DNSTIMEOUT    3000 /* Max. number of ms for first try */
#define DNS_MAX_EVENTS 10000
#define DNS_MAX_SERVERS 2
#define SERVERS    "1.0.0.1,8.8.8.8" /* DNS server to use (Cloudflare & Google) */
#define MAXDOMAINS 8192
#define PORT 80
#define MAXBUF 1024
#define MAX_EPOLL_EVENTS 8192
#define MAX_CONNECTIONS 8192
#define TIMEOUT 10000
ares_socket_t dns_client_fds[ARES_GETSOCK_MAXNUM] = {0};
struct epoll_event ev, dns_events[DNS_MAX_EVENTS];
int i,bitmask,nfds, epollfd, timeout, fd_count, ret;
int epfd;
int sockfd[MAX_CONNECTIONS];
struct epoll_event event[MAX_CONNECTIONS];
struct sockaddr_in dest[MAX_CONNECTIONS];
char resolved[MAXDOMAINS][254];
char ips[MAXDOMAINS][128];
int current = 0, active = 0, next = 0;
char servers[MAX_CONNECTIONS][128];
char domains[MAX_CONNECTIONS][254];
char get_buffer[MAX_CONNECTIONS][1024];
char buffer[MAX_CONNECTIONS][MAXBUF];
int buffer_used[MAX_CONNECTIONS];
struct timespec startTime, stopTime;
int i, num_ready, connections = 0, done = 0, total_bytes = 0, total_domains = 0, iterations = 0, count = 0;
FILE * fp;
struct epoll_event events[MAX_EPOLL_EVENTS];
static int nwaiting;

static void state_cb(void *data, int s, int read, int write)
{
    //printf("Change state fd %d read:%d write:%d\n", s, read, write);
}

static void callback(void *arg, int status, int timeouts, struct hostent *host)
{
    nwaiting--;

    if(!host || status != ARES_SUCCESS){
        //fprintf(stderr, "Failed to lookup %s\n", ares_strerror(status));
        return;
    }

    char ip[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];

    if (host->h_addr_list[0] != NULL){
        inet_ntop(host->h_addrtype, host->h_addr_list[0], ip, sizeof(ip));
        strcpy(resolved[current], host->h_name);
        strcpy(ips[current], ip);
        if (current < MAXDOMAINS - 1) current++; else current = 0;
        active++;
        printf("active %d\r", active);
    }
}

static void wait_ares(ares_channel channel)
{
    nfds=0;
    bitmask=0;
    for (i =0; i < DNS_MAX_SERVERS ; i++) {
        if (dns_client_fds[i] > 0) {
            if (epoll_ctl(epollfd, EPOLL_CTL_DEL, dns_client_fds[i], NULL) < 0) {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    memset(dns_client_fds, 0, sizeof(dns_client_fds));
    bitmask = ares_getsock(channel, dns_client_fds, DNS_MAX_SERVERS);
    for (i =0; i < DNS_MAX_SERVERS ; i++) {
       if (dns_client_fds[i] > 0) {
            ev.events = 0;
            if (ARES_GETSOCK_READABLE(bitmask, i)) {
                ev.events |= EPOLLIN;
            }
            if (ARES_GETSOCK_WRITABLE(bitmask, i)) {
                ev.events |= EPOLLOUT;
            }
            ev.data.fd = dns_client_fds[i];
            if (epoll_ctl(epollfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, dns_client_fds[i], &ev) < 0) {
                if(errno == EEXIST) {
                    nfds++;
                    continue;
                }
                continue;
            }
            nfds++;
        }
    }
    if(nfds==0)
    {
        return;
    }
    timeout = 1000;//millisecs
    fd_count = epoll_wait(epollfd, dns_events, DNS_MAX_EVENTS, timeout);
    if (fd_count < 0) {
        return;
    }
    if (fd_count > 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < fd_count; ++i) {
            ares_process_fd(channel, ((dns_events[i].events) & (EPOLLIN) ? dns_events[i].data.fd:ARES_SOCKET_BAD), ((dns_events[i].events) & (EPOLLOUT)? dns_events[i].data.fd:ARES_SOCKET_BAD));
        }
    } else {
        ares_process_fd(channel, ARES_SOCKET_BAD, ARES_SOCKET_BAD);
    }       
}

void make_socket_and_connect (int sock)
{
    if ( (sockfd[sock] = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0)) < 0 ) {
        perror("Socket");
        exit(errno);
    }
    count++;
    event[sock].events = EPOLLIN|EPOLLOUT;
    event[sock].data.fd = sockfd[sock];
    epoll_ctl(epfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, sockfd[sock], &event[sock]);
    bzero(&dest[sock], sizeof(dest[sock]));
    dest[sock].sin_family = AF_INET;
    dest[sock].sin_port = htons(PORT);
    if ( inet_pton(AF_INET, servers[sock], &dest[sock].sin_addr.s_addr) == 0 ) {
        printf("\n");
        perror(servers[sock]);
        exit(errno);
    }
    if ( connect(sockfd[sock], (struct sockaddr*)&dest[sock], sizeof(dest[sock])) != 0 ) {
        if(errno != EINPROGRESS) {
            printf("%s\n", servers[sock]);
            perror("Connect again ");
            //exit(errno);
        }
        buffer_used[sock] = 0;
    }
}

int is_valid_ip(char *domain)
{
    if (!strcmp(domain, "255.255.255.255"))
        return 0;
    if (!strcmp(domain, "192.168.1.0"))
        return 0;
    if (!strcmp(domain, "127.0.0.0"))
        return 0;
        
    return 1;
}

void close_socket (int socket)
{
    close(sockfd[socket]);
    count--;
    epoll_ctl(epfd, EPOLL_CTL_DEL, sockfd[socket], &event[socket]);
}

void get_domain_and_ip(int id)
{
    //close_socket(id);
    active--;
get_domain_name:
    strcpy(servers[id], ips[next]);
    strcpy(domains[id], resolved[next]);
    if (next < (MAXDOMAINS - 1)) next++; else next = 0;
    if (is_valid_ip(servers[id]))
    {
        make_socket_and_connect(id);
        total_domains++;
    }
    else
        goto get_domain_name;                
}

void get_domain_and_ip_without_connect(int id)
{
get_domain_name2:
    strcpy(servers[id], ips[next]);
    strcpy(domains[id], resolved[next]);
    if (next < (MAXDOMAINS - 1)) next++; else next = 0;
    if (!is_valid_ip(servers[id]))
        goto get_domain_name2;                
}

void get_time()
{
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &stopTime);
    uint64_t msElapsed = (stopTime.tv_nsec - startTime.tv_nsec) / 1000000 + (stopTime.tv_sec - startTime.tv_sec) * 1000;
    double seconds = (double)msElapsed / 1000.0;
    iterations++;
    fprintf(stderr, "iterations=%d total domains=%d elapsed=%2.2fs domains/s=%2.2f KB=%d Mbit/s=%2.2f num_ready=%d count=%d active=%d next=%d current=%d.....\r"
            , iterations, total_domains, seconds, total_domains/seconds, total_bytes/1024, 8*total_bytes/seconds/1024/1204, num_ready, count, active, next, current);
}

ssize_t send_data(int id)
{
    ssize_t nByte = send(sockfd[id], get_buffer[id] + buffer_used[id], strlen(get_buffer[id]) - buffer_used[id], 0);
    return nByte;
}

ssize_t recv_data(int id)
{
    ssize_t nByte = recv(sockfd[id], buffer[id], sizeof(buffer[id]), 0);
    return nByte;
}

int wait()
{
    int ret = epoll_wait(epfd, events, MAX_EPOLL_EVENTS, TIMEOUT/*timeout*/);
    return ret;
}
                
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        
    sigaction(SIGPIPE, &(struct sigaction){SIG_IGN}, NULL);
    FILE * fp;
    char domain[254];
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;
    ares_channel channel;
    int status, dns_done = 0;
    int optmask;
    
    status = ares_library_init(ARES_LIB_INIT_ALL);
    if (status != ARES_SUCCESS) {
        printf("ares_library_init: %s\n", ares_strerror(status));
        return 1;
    }

    struct ares_options options = {
        .timeout = DNSTIMEOUT,     /* set first query timeout */
        .tries = MAXTRIES       /* set max. number of tries */
    };
    optmask = ARES_OPT_TIMEOUTMS | ARES_OPT_TRIES;

    status = ares_init_options(&channel, &options, optmask);
    if (status != ARES_SUCCESS) {
        printf("ares_init_options: %s\n", ares_strerror(status));
        return 1;
    }

    status = ares_set_servers_csv(channel, SERVERS);
    if (status != ARES_SUCCESS) {
        printf("ares_set_servers_csv: %s\n", ares_strerror(status));
        return 1;
    }
    
    memset(dns_client_fds, 0, sizeof(dns_client_fds));
    memset((char *)&ev, 0, sizeof(struct epoll_event));
    memset((char *)&dns_events[0], 0, sizeof(dns_events));

    epollfd = epoll_create(DNS_MAX_SERVERS);
    
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (!fp)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    do{
        if (nwaiting >= MAXWAITING || dns_done) {
            do {
                wait_ares(channel);
                
            } while (nwaiting > MAXWAITING);
        }
        if (!dns_done) {
            if (fscanf(fp, "%253s", domain) == 1) {
                ares_gethostbyname(channel, domain, AF_INET, callback, NULL);
                nwaiting++;
            } else {
                //fprintf(stderr, "done sending\n");
                dns_done = 1;
            }
        }
    } while (active < MAX_CONNECTIONS);
    
    /*---Open sockets for streaming---*/
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_CONNECTIONS; i++)
    { 
        if ( (sockfd[i] = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0)) < 0 ) {
            perror("Socket");
            exit(errno);
        }
        count++;
    }

    /*---Add sockets to epoll---*/
    epfd = epoll_create1(0);
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_CONNECTIONS; i++)
    {
        event[i].events = EPOLLIN|EPOLLOUT; 
        event[i].data.fd = sockfd[i];
        epoll_ctl(epfd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, sockfd[i], &event[i]);
    }
    
    /*---Initialize server address/port structs---*/
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_CONNECTIONS; i++)
    {
        get_domain_and_ip_without_connect(i);
        //printf("%s %s\n", servers[i], domains[i]);
        bzero(&dest[i], sizeof(dest[i]));
        dest[i].sin_family = AF_INET;
        dest[i].sin_port = htons(PORT);
        if ( inet_pton(AF_INET, servers[i], &dest[i].sin_addr.s_addr) == 0 ) {
           perror(servers[i]);
           exit(errno);
        }
    }
    
    /*---Connect to servers---*/
    for (i = 0; i < MAX_CONNECTIONS; i++)
    {
        if ( connect(sockfd[i], (struct sockaddr*)&dest[i], sizeof(dest[i])) != 0 ) {
            if(errno != EINPROGRESS) {
                perror("Connect ");
                //exit(errno);
            }
            buffer_used[i] = 0;
        }
    }
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &startTime);
    while (1)
    {
        /*---Do async DNS---*/
        while (active < MAXDOMAINS && nwaiting > 0) {
            //printf("active = %d MAXDOMAINS = %d nwaiting = %d MAXWAITING = %d\n", active, MAXDOMAINS, nwaiting, MAXWAITING);
            if (nwaiting >= MAXWAITING || dns_done) {
                do {
                    wait_ares(channel);
                } while (nwaiting > MAXWAITING);
            }
            if (!dns_done) {
                if (fscanf(fp, "%253s", domain) == 1) {
                    ares_gethostbyname(channel, domain, AF_INET, callback, NULL);
                    nwaiting++;
                } else {
                    //fprintf(stderr, "done sending\n");
                    dns_done = 1;
                }
            }
        } //while (active < MAXDOMAINS);
        /*---Wait to be able to send---*/
        num_ready = wait();
        get_time();
        if (!num_ready) break;
        for(i = 0; i < num_ready; i++) {
            int index;
            if(events[i].events & EPOLLOUT) {
                for (int j = 0; j < MAX_CONNECTIONS; j++)
                {
                    if (events[i].data.fd == sockfd[j])
                    {
                        index = j;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                snprintf(get_buffer[index], sizeof(get_buffer[index]), 
                "GET %s HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: %s\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36\r\n\r\n", "/", domains[i]);
                ssize_t nByte = 0;
                if (buffer_used[index] < strlen(get_buffer[index]))
                    nByte = send_data(index);
                if (nByte > 0)
                {
                    buffer_used[index] += nByte;
                    total_bytes += nByte;
                }
                if (nByte == -1 && errno == EPIPE)
                {
                    get_domain_and_ip(index);
                }
            }
            if(events[i].events & EPOLLIN) {
                for (int j = 0; j < MAX_CONNECTIONS; j++)
                {
                    if (events[i].data.fd == sockfd[j])
                    {
                        index = j;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                bzero(buffer[index], MAXBUF);
                ssize_t nByte = recv_data(index);
                //if (nByte > 0) printf("Received: %s from %s at %s \n", buffer[index], domains[index], servers[index]);
                if (nByte > 0) total_bytes += nByte;
                if (nByte == 0)
                {
                    close_socket(index);
                    if (!done)
                    {
                        get_domain_and_ip(index);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        get_time();
        if (done && count == 0) break;
    }
    ares_destroy(channel);
    ares_library_cleanup();
    fclose(fp);
    printf("\nFinished without errors\n");
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT

As requested I've performed more extensive testing with smaller numbers of concurrent connections. The results are below. The results are for 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256 and 512 concurrent connections.

```
total domains=4 elapsed=60.37s domains/s=0.07 KB=5 Mbit/s=0.00
total domains=0 elapsed=60.39s domains/s=0.00 KB=5 Mbit/s=0.00
total domains=17 elapsed=60.40s domains/s=0.28 KB=73 Mbit/s=0.01
total domains=17 elapsed=60.48s domains/s=0.28 KB=106 Mbit/s=0.01
total domains=40 elapsed=60.45s domains/s=0.66 KB=189 Mbit/s=0.02
total domains=172 elapsed=60.37s domains/s=2.85 KB=907 Mbit/s=0.10
total domains=312 elapsed=60.56s domains/s=5.15 KB=1272 Mbit/s=0.14
total domains=1165 elapsed=60.65s domains/s=19.21 KB=5687 Mbit/s=0.62
total domains=1966 elapsed=60.34s domains/s=32.58 KB=9884 Mbit/s=1.09
```

The tests show that for smaller numbers of concurrent connections we do see an increase in performance for increasing numbers of concurrent connections.

EDIT

As requested in chat here is a link to the file of domains I am testing with. Warning - the file is over 2GB in size. It has over 130M domains. [domains](https://www.wottot.com/com.lowercase) Or if you just want 100,000 here is another link to play with [100,000 domains](https://www.wottot.com/100000)

Comment: _Side note:_ Whenever I see _multiple_ arrays indexed by the same index, I think about merging into a struct: `struct connection { int sockfd; struct epoll_event event; struct sockaddr_in dest; char servers[128]; char domains[254]; char get_buffer[1024]; char buffer[MAXBUF]; int buffer_used; }; struct connection connect_list[MAX_CONNECTIONS];` It can make the logic more clean/clear [and deref of a single struct pointer can be faster]. There are at least two other lists that can benefit from this approach. And, `goto`???

Comment: How do you measure performance? Do you know the performance of the DNS server you are hitting?

Comment: 8000 connections? Did you try a _lower_ number (e.g. 20)? After a certain number of threads/processes/connections (e.g. 2x the number of CPUs) the system will spend most of its time in task switch and swamp the memory bus. Do you know how many packets are being [silently] _dropped_ due to insufficient kernel socket descriptors or other resources, CPU utilization, etc? The overhead of copyin/copyout from kernel space to userspace buffers? Did you look at `PACKET_MMAP` (i.e. zero copy from kernel to userspace)?

Comment: @CraigEstey I have edited the question to show testing with lower numbers of concurrent connections. The tests show that there is an increase in performance with higher numbers of concurrent connections. Regarding context switching this is a single threaded application. There is no context switching by design. The CPU utilization is 100% on one core. I'm looking into ```PACKET_MMAP``` as you suggested. It looks promising. Any more optimisations I could make?

Comment: How many cores? And, what is the utilization for the others? You're only using one process and, hence, only one CPU? You may want _multiple_ threads to distribute the load. You may want to look at `irqbalance`. This distributes the _interrupt_ handling (in the kernel) across multiple cores by changing the IRQ affinity to various CPUs. Ideally, you want the NIC to interrupt on the same core as your userspace process (so no interprocessor overhead)

Comment: @CraigEstey The machine I am testing on has 8 cores. 1 core is running at 100% usage while the other 7 are pretty much idle. How do I control which core the NIC interrupts on?

Comment: With high enough number of connections, the `epoll` overhead may swamp things. You might be better off with just a spin loop (against `PACKET_MMAP`), similar to what the kernel does with NAPI: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_API That is, `epoll` is similar to one interrupt per packet instead of NAPI-style polling. Note that with `PACKET_MMAP`, once the app gets control, it can process many packets at once (it looks at the ring buffer indexes) without going back to the kernel.

Comment: See: `sched_irqaffinity` and `sched_cpuaffinity`. But, this is _tricky_. To utilize IRQ affinity, you may have to _disable_ the `irqbalance` kernel thread--may be counterproductive, so do as a last resort. Note that to spread the load and utilize all CPUs, you'll need to go multithreaded.

Comment: Although a bit dated, of possible interest: https://blog.cloudflare.com/kernel-bypass/

Comment: Also, I've talked about this before. Here's an old answer of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63234685/qt-qtcpsocket-reading-data-overlap-causes-invalid-tcp-behavior-during-high-bandw/63237645#63237645 I'd forgotten about this, but it seems I'm still giving out the same advice

Comment: *The tests show that for smaller numbers of concurrent connections we do see an increase in performance for increasing numbers of concurrent connections.*  That won't continue indefinitely. There are a multitude of limits. Have you tried seeing if the DNS servers you're using rate limit you?

Comment: @CraigEstey The ```PACKET_MMAP``` tutorial says to call ```bind``` on the file descriptor first. Surely, in my case I can skip this step as my application is a client and not a server?

Comment: I think you _need_ to because it's `PF_PACKET`. IIRC, it needs to bind to the _interface_ which is slightly different than ordinary/normal bind because of `SIOCGIFINDEX` and `struct ifreq`. Note that you're going to get _all_ packets to/from the interface (not just the given socket connection/host). See my other answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54056426/af-packet-and-ethernet/54057044#54057044 In other words, `PF_PACKET/PACKET_MMAP` connects to an _interface_ rather than a host/IP address

Comment: Do I have to use ```PF_PACKET```? If I use ```PF_PACKET``` I have to use ```SOCK_RAW```. Does that mean I have to construct the packets myself? Do I lose TCP functionality? Sorry if these are basic questions. I've never done this before.

Comment: You can use _either_ `SOCK_RAW` or `SOCK_DGRAM` as `socktype` in the `socket(PF_PACKET,socktype,...)` call. See `man 7 packet`

Comment: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/pt/man7/packet.7.html says ``` The connect(2) operation is not supported on packet sockets.``` Doesn't that derail the whole thing? My application is a client not a server. How can I communicate with the servers if I can't even connect to them?

Comment: You might try doing the multithreading first. You'll need that to spread out the load across all CPUs. You could do that with your existing method. I _would_ refactor to use `struct` as I mentioned above as it will make the multithread code much easier. After that is working, you could add in `PACKET_MMAP`. You could make this an option, so you can flip back and forth and benchmark to see if the throughput [improvement] is worth the complexity.

Comment: As far as I can see the HTTP communication is the bottleneck which certainly requires a connect. What should I do? Use raw packets and do the handshake myself with hand crafted packets?

Comment: I saw the DNS part, which is datagram, but missed the scrape of the http/html home page. As I said, I'd switch to multithreading first. This will improve the performance/throughput of regular `AF_INET`. You'll need multiple threads even with `PACKET_MMAP` because you don't want to delay/sleep the network I/O when you do `write` on a file to save the results of the page fetch. So, you put the write-to-file in a separate thread.

Comment: When I use wrk to stress test a server I am able to throttle the available bandwidth with a single thread. Is there some major difference between communicating with one server as opposed to many? Apart from being able to keep the connection alive and reuse sockets I don't see how the two cases should be so different.

Comment: @CraigEstey I've started creating a ```PACKET_MMAP``` version. However, one thing keeps bugging me. Nginx, which is ```epoll``` based doesn't seem to suffer from the problems I'm describing so I can't help but feel that there is some problem with my ```epoll``` implementation that could be solved before going down the ```PACKET_MMAP``` route.

Comment: There _are_ issues. You're doing `socket` in a loop to open 8000 sockets. This can't work because the limit is number of file descriptors (1024). I've been restructuring your program [partly for me]. I've put most similar stuff in a struct. I was/am going to post it back when done. The basic idea is: (1) get free struct and read IP from line (2) resolve DNS (3) open http socket (4) pull all html data (5) close socket (6) return struct to free list Each of these steps in a separate thread. Each step has a linked list for its input. So, this is like a shell pipeline

Comment: Because you've got arrays instead of linked lists, the program spends a lot of time looping on things that are inactive/dummy entries

Comment: Plus, it's possible that `poll` is faster/better than `epoll`, To add/del an entry to the poll "set", for `poll` it's just a function call. For `epoll`, it's a syscall (much higher overhead).

Comment: @CraigEstey but ```epoll``` was invented because of deficiencies with ```poll```.

Comment: AFAICT, for your use case, `poll` will work as well as `epoll` [if not better]. But, if you go multithread, you can [and should] eliminate polling altogether.

Comment: But my understanding is that Nginx works better than Apache because it abandons the threaded model in favour of an ```epoll``` based model?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240873/discussion-between-craig-estey-and-james-read).